# hover not working on <button> inside div, works outside

Tags: html, css, button, nested, hover

This does not give me a hover state for my  element:

```css
.button:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div id="frame1">
    <p id="txt1" class="white droid">Some dogs</p>
    <p id="txt2" class="white droid">Don't like to bark</p>
    <button class="button">Reverse!</button>
  </div>  
  <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

If I change the HTML to the below, the button does give me a hover state:

```css
.button:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div id="frame1">
    <p id="txt1" class="white droid">Some dogs</p>
    <p id="txt2" class="white droid">Don't like to bark</p>
  </div>   
  <div id="border"></div>
  <button class="button">Reverse!</button>
</div>
```

Note: the DIVs containing the button are just set to absolute positioning.

Is there something I need to do to get hover state with the button in a nested DIV?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You'll need to provide **ALL** the *related* CSS to reproduce the issue.

Comment: ...especially the positioning...

Comment: I tried your demo, and [it works fine](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#39931f5a38904d0d4f21961ac55a4c42). It's clear your not showing all the code, so it's possible you may have conflicting CSS in your main style sheet. Can't help if I don't know what I'm working with.

Comment: Your current code doesn't reproduce your error.... it's either specific to your chosen browser, or, as above, we don't have the code that's causing it. You could probably find the offending, overriding line via element inspection on like, Firebug fairly easily, but this is something you'll have to do yourself.

Comment: on Firefox Mac it works - apparently a browser issue

Answer (score 0):

Hm in chrome for some reason I only got it to work by increasing z index on button. I shall follow the advice and look in developer tools for the offending line. Sorry, I should have posted all code. Need coffe now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, I don't know if this is right way of doing it, but increasing z-index of anchor tag(a), so that it is above it's parent div, did the trick for me

```css
.showcase__content a {
    background: rgba(41, 88, 85, 0.707);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.449);
    color: var(--tertiary-color);
    font-weight: 900;
    z-index: 2;
}

.showcase__content>a :hover {
    background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.449);
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
        <section id="showcase">
            <div class="showcase__content">
                <h1 class="showcase__content--title">Scarlett Tyler</h1>
                <p class="showcase__content--para">
                    UX Designer / Frontend Developer
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="showcase__content--link">My Work</a>
            </div>
        </section>
```